# soundcloud api - too many requests

Tags: api, soundcloud, throttling

My soundcloud app (that makes quite a lot of requests) recently started receiving the error:

429 - Too Many Requests

for all DELETE commands (when I attempt to delete a follow relationship). This was working perfectly last week. Do throttling limits exist for soundcloud api requests? I looked through the developer's guide but haven't found anything yet. The support page said to post a question here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A 429 Status indicates that your application is making too many requests to the /me/followings endpoint. This isn't throttling per say, but an attempt to circumvent follow-spam applications.

How many requests are you making and with what frequency? If you back off for a while, are you able to get a successful response?

Comment: I waited a day and yes, it works again so yes, I'm being throttled.

What are the official limits?

Comment: The current limit is 250 / day for applications attached to premium accounts and 100 / day for free accounts. These are subject to change based on data we collect about usage.

Comment: Does this just mean that you have to have a 'pro account' or 'pro unlimited'? or is there a special account for extra api requests? Just curious because I may potentially be using a lot of requests. Is there also a best practice on validating soundcloud urls? We are going to allow users to enter artists and then associate them with soundcloud accounts. I'd like to validate them with resolve but that would be a lot of requests.

Comment: Also, is there a way to get your daily limit number at all so I can keep track of it on the admin side?